# Stop simple timer with a tread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, handler

I'm trying to stop a timer from a thread which start the count. When i press the "START" button everything is okay, but at the moment i press the "STOP" button i get the next error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.user.a4_1_basic_handler, PID: 20375
>                                                                                        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick

I'm new at this, i'm just trying to put in practice **thread** using **handler**. If someone can tell me how to finish the thread that will be a plus :)

```
package com.example.user.a4_1_basic_handler;


import android.os.Handler;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Java variables
int num =0;
boolean stopThread=false;
//Android variables
static final String S_TAG=MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
Handler handler;
Thread counter = new Thread(new tstart());
tstart test;
// UI
TextView textView;
Button start_button;
Button stop_button;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Log.i(S_TAG,"OnCreate Thread ID: "+Thread.currentThread().getId());
    handler = new Handler(getApplicationContext().getMainLooper());
    tstart test;

    textView=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    start_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.start_button);
    stop_button=(Button) findViewById(R.id.stop_button);
}
//UI
public void OnClick_start(View view){
    counter.start();
}
public void OnClick_stop(View view){
    test.finish();
}
//Methods
public void timer(){
    num++;
    textView.setText(String.valueOf(num));
}
public void clock(){
    try {Thread.sleep(1000);}
    catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
}
//Thread
class tstart extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!stopThread) {
            clock();
            textView.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    timer();
                }
            });
        }
    }
    public void finish(){
        stopThread=true;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`test` is not initialisd.

```
 Thread counter = new Thread(new tstart());
```

What is the need of `counter`, inside `onCreate()` create object of `test`

```
test=new tstart();
```

And use `test` instead of `counter`

```
public void OnClick_start(View view){
    test.start();
}
```

---

Why don't you try Standard Java timer [java.util.Timer](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Timer.html) and [java.util.TimerTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TimerTask.html) that works fine in Android.

Comment: Thanks you so much! I will use the libraries that you refer to me later. Now I am trying to fully understand threads with dummies exercises.

Comment: you declared `tstart test;` globally and locally inside `onCreate()` method but never initialised and start using that object reference inside `OnClick_stop` method.